# increase binary executable size

Tags: c

Abstract problem:
I have some code in C. 
After compilation the executable has 604 KB. 
I'd like it to be bigger, let's say 100 MB.

How to achieve this?

I could declare a string to increase binary size, but is there any more scalable solution. That is I'd like to increase compiled size by N bytes without increasing source code by N bytes.

```
 char* filler = "filler"; // increases compiled size only by few bytes
```

Use case:
I'm developing firmware, and testing remote firmware upgrade feature. I'd like to see how it will behave when firmware is big and heavy.

Comment: What you mean by "scalable"?

Comment: *"Abstract problem"* - No, you can't get off so easy, I'm curious. Why are you really asking? :)

Comment: is something like `echo abcd >> myprogram.exe` an option?

Comment: I just glanced through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

The executable file (ABI) follows that layout. As you can see there are a lot of size and offset fiels all over the place, so if you want to attach a dead section, you might have to modify those sizes and offsets.

A suggestion: use bash scripts (or even some code within your makefile) to generate a .c file on the go while compiling and get it included in project. You can automate the process of specifying the size of the const char array in the command like when issuing make.

Comment: @el.pescado I added explanation in question

Comment: @StoryTeller read "Use case"

Comment: Shouldn't declaring a large global array suffice for your purpose? Such as `char someGlobalArray[100 * 1024 * 1024];`? Possibly, you might have to touch it somehow inside your code to prevent the compiler from optimising it away... Or with GCC, there might be some attribute you can apply to to force GCC leaving the array untouched.

Comment: `__attribute__((used))` should do the trick...

Comment: @Aconcagua uninitialised statics will be stored as only their length.

Comment: Build it with debug everything.  Debug versions of the libraries, local symbols, bounds-checking, stack-checking.  Turn off all optimization.  That should bloat it out quite nicely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This creates a 100MB executable when compiled with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100000000

char dummy[SIZE] = {'a'};

int main(void){
    dummy[SIZE-1] = '\n';
    if(dummy[0] == 'a')printf("Hello, bloated world");
    return 0;
}
```

By defining the array outside of `main` you don't blow the stack. By using the array, gcc doesn't optimize it away.

Comment: Note that at least one non-zero initializer is needed, otherwise you won't get a large executable.

Comment: That's nice. I tried it, but I didn't used the array so it was optimized.

Comment: @dbush I noticed that. That is why I switched to `'a'`. I initially tried it with `'\0'` and was surprised that the executable was still small. I don't really understand why that is.

Comment: All-zero variables are typically grouped together, and initalized with one big `memset` before calling `main` to keep executabe size down.

Comment: @JohnColeman: It's because elements initialized to zero will be placed in the BSS section, and not present in the executable, because the loader can construct them at run time.

Answer (score 9):

GCC specific variant:

```
char dummy[100*1024*1024] __attribute__((used)) = { 77 };
```

Applying the attribute 'used', you do not need to touch it any more to prevent it from being optimised away. Still, an non-all-null initialiser must be applied as in John Coleman's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a global array with all elements explicitly initialized.  The elements should be randomized, otherwise the compiler is likely to optimize the initializer list in the compiled code.

You first need a separate program to generate your array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int len = 100000000;
    int i;
    srand(getpid());
    printf("unsigned char buf[%d] = {\n", len);
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        printf(" %hhu,", rand() & 0xff);
        if (i%16==15) printf("\n");
    }
    printf("};\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Run this and redirect the output to a file:

```
./array_generator > array.c
```

Then you'll get array.c which looks something like this:

```
unsigned char buf[1000000] = { 
247, 223, 30, 51, 46, 247, 133, 136, 254, 225, 82, 135, 68, 176, 240, 7,
29, 245, 104, 203, 230, 83, 127, 189, 37, 5, 168, 105, 134, 9, 229, 125,
232, 3, 176, 23, 251, 53, 159, 249, 22, 241, 128, 90, 161, 112, 97, 191,
101, 202, 138, 75, 29, 10, 9, 66, 15, 177, 171, 149, 186, 145, 18, 163,
...
};
```

Then you include this in your main source:

```
#include  "array.c"
```

Comment: Not to be overly critical, but question did ask for *"...without increasing source code by N bytes."*. This works, but JohnColemans solution should probably tested first: many embedded compilers are not that good at optimizing initializer lists.

Comment: @user694733 That's a good point, and if the compiler in question doesn't optimize the initializer list then one of the other methods would be best. If that's not the case, then at least with this method you don't need to manually create a large source file.